# Check for an anchor

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if the current page has an anchor

so I am using this

```
var qs = window.location.hash;
```

then checking if qs is not an empty string

```
if (qs !== '') {
```

Is this the correct way to do that? It seems to work, but I am confusing myself reading about JavaScript's various ways to check for null/undefined/empty string.

Comment: `hash` is the hash, not the query string. As in `#name_of_anchor`, not `?name=value`. Which did you want to check for?

Comment: This is actually called an *[anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)*, not a *bookmark*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `window.location.hash` only contains inner page links/anchors (those that follow a hash (`#`) symbol)
- `window.location.search` contains the query string with a `?` prefix

Using your conditional (if-statement) is fine.  If the property is not populated it will be a blank string.

Comment: sorry - i used the wrong terminology - I need to check if the page has an bookmark/anchor (i.e. www.aaa.com/page#xx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, beside the fact that I'd go for `document.location.hash`, that is a correct and reasonable way to check for.

You can just check `if (!qs) { }`. By using `!` all possible falsy values are covered.

Comment: 1) you should use `window.location` over `document.location`.  2) advising people to compare falsy increases their chances of messing something else up in the future; it's best to test for an expected value

Comment: @vol7ron: unless you are scared that IE4 breaks, `document.location` will just link to `window.location`. 2) I'd prefer to check for falsy value before checking explicitly against the empty string. But its probably wise in this situation to aim for `if( qs && qs.length )` anyway.

Comment: jAndy: right and I'd like that better, especially since it would future-proof it :) btw, the downvote was not from me;  @Domenic: wrong

Comment: @vol7ron There are no cases in which `!!(qs && qs.length) !== !!(qs)`.

Comment: @Domenic: perhaps, but `if(!qs)` could mean that qs was never assigned (undefined).  Whereas something like Dark Falcon's approach (`if (typeof(qs) == 'string' && qs != '' && qs != '#')`) would make sure it is a string (was assigned).  This is nit-picking but, if you're evaluating inside something that's out of global scope, especially something that's deeply nested, it could save effort using the long approach.  This particular question was kind of basic though, so everyone wins :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
var qs = window.location.hash;
if (typeof(qs) == 'string' && qs != '' && qs != '#')
```

Note that the proper one to use is `window.location`, as this is the standard. `document.location` is not standardized. [window.location in the standard.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location)

Comment: For `hash` to be populated it has to have more than `#`; in other words, if there is a blank string that follows the hash (`www.google.com#`), window.location.hash will not be `#`

Comment: According to the standard, yes. In actuality, I have seen browsers return "#" for a URL ending in "#". (IE, I'm looking at you!)

Comment: you'd know better than me :)  the only improvement I'd see is that you should use the exact operators (`===` vs `==`  and `!==` vs `!=`)